# How to compute perpendicular distance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, distance, computational-geometry

I have a matrix `A` (Mx2), and matrix `B` (Nx2), with M>=N. 
I have to compute the perpendicular euclidean distance to test similarity between A and B. Refering to the image, a single euclidean distance is the segment between each pi and p'i, once computed every single perpendicular distance, I can compute the mean or the sum to get a single parameter. Do you know a matlab routine or such a script that do this?
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't m be equal to n exactly in this case?

Comment: Dashed line is the compressed version of the solid line, so, obviously has less points than original trajectory. After all to compute the distance, it will be necessary create phony points, so dashed and solid line will have same number of points. But, the phony points created on the dashed line must have the minimum distance from respective point on the solid line. How can I do this?

Comment: There seems to be some information missing. For example, referring to the image, how is it decided that p0-p5 will be joined by a single dashed line and p5-p16 will be joined by another dashed line. Also, do you mean to say that data in A corresponds to the solid line and the data in B corresponds to the dashed line?

Comment: @Mariano Do you mean that you should find the best subset from p1,p2,..pn, such that the mean of the distances is minimized?

Comment: @Abhinav This is because i have choosen a given threshold as error metric. If I choose 0 as threshold factor solid line and dashed line will be perfectly equal. Yes, A is the solid line and B is the compressed version of A (the dashed line).

Comment: @Andrey No. I'm not intersted in what's the best. I have this two trajectories A and B (B is a compressed version of A). I wanna mesure now every single perpendicular distance, so If I have a third trajectory C (C is another compressed version of A) I could say: B is better than C.

Comment: Are these both functions, such that the ordinate (x) value is monotonically increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that p1 .. p4 lie between p0 and p5, then you can use the area of a triangle to calculate the perpendicular distance easily:

```
d(p0p5, p1) = 2 * area(p0p1p5) / norm(p5-p0)
```

The area of a triangle is found by

```
area(p0p1p5) = sqrt(s * (s-norm(p0-p1)) * (s-norm(p1-p5)) * (s-norm(p5-p0)))
```

where

```
s = (norm(p0-p1) + norm(p1-p5) + norm(p5-p0)) / 2
```

I think you can gain a performance improvement using the dot product for projection and pythagorean theorem:

```
d(p0p5, p1) = sqrt(norm(p1-p0)^2 - dot(p1-p0,p5-p0)^2/norm(p5-p0)^2)
```

In either case, if your cost function involves mean-squared error, you can eliminate the `sqrt` call by just evaluating the squared-error instead.  Norm-squares are also cheaper to calculate than calling `norm` and then squaring (use a dot product instead).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dist` from Neural Network Toolbox.

`A` and `B` being n x 2 matrices, this is one possible way to calculate the sum of distances (pseudo-code): sum(sqrt((A_1x - B_1x)^2 + (A_1y - B_1y)^2), ...,  sqrt((A_nx - B_nx)^2 + (A_ny - B_ny)^2), or: sum(p1-p'1, ..., pn-p'n).

Each of these matrices (`A` and `B`) holds x and y coordinates of n points in 2D space (in this example n = 3).

```
% Some example matrices, size 3 x 2.

A = [ 10 22; 35 48; 16 42 ];
B = [ 5 7; 8 11; 33 22 ];

DistanceMatrix = dist([A' B']);
DistanceMatrix(1:size(A,1),:) = [];
SumOfDistances = sum(diag(DistanceMatrix));

SumOfDistances =
87.8641
```